# Webpack 4: Creating loaders as functions (with the ability to send options)

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, webpack-loader

I may be missing something obvious, but I can't seem to be able to create a Webpack 4 loader as a simple function that can take `options`:

```
rules: [{
  test: /\.csv$/,
  loader: function() {
    // ...
  },
  options: {
    // ...
  }
}]
```

I dare not assume Webpack is so obstinate about loaders having to be npm packages, but I'm struggling to find an example where using a simple function as a loader works as intended.

Can someone help we with the most basic example of how to get something like this to work?

P.S. in the example config above, the function is imported from another file, just added it inline for clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Webpack loader should simply export a function that returns a string of code and an optional source map.

```
var loaderUtils = require('loader-utils');

export default function(source) {
    const options = loaderUtils.getOptions(this) || {};
    // Get the value of options.testOption from Webpack config
    var testOption = options.testOption;

    // ...

    return `export default ${JSON.stringify(source)}`;
}
```

This is a barebones example. [`loader-utils`](https://github.com/webpack/loader-utils) is used in most loaders to easily get the options passed to it from the Webpack configuration file. [`schema-utils`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/schema-utils) can also be incorporated to validate the options.

As for where to put this code, write it in a file named `loader.js` in whatever directory you want. Use it in your Webpack configuration with something like this:

```
rules: [{
    test: /\.csv$/,
    use: {
        loader: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/loader.js'),
        options: {
            testOption: 'test string'
        }
    }
}]
```

See Webpack's guide to [writing a loader](https://webpack.js.org/contribute/writing-a-loader/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, @Adam! I think what I was missing is that a loader _needs_ to be an external file, as per https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/119 and https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/698, which is not really captured in the "Writing a Loader" docs?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't cover that point, but you're correct that it has to be external.